# WGS-84 Co-ordinates

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, wgs84, sharpkml

I have following set of Co-ordinates

```
0.00852919145063922,0.000000,0.000000,-0.00852919145063922,-117.210491069447,34.8362619850852
```

This is the format of WGS-84. Please let me know what does the first point denote, second point denote upto 5th point.

Comment: We need more information.  Where did those coordinates come from?  The last two numbers _might_ be longitude and latitude if [the point is supposed to be near Barstow, CA](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.8362619850852,-117.210491069447&hl=en&ll=34.83635,-117.210388&spn=1.048269,1.783905&sll=40.85968,-74.157769&sspn=0.241483,0.445976&t=h&z=10).

Comment: These points are coming from the database which has images captured through radar.

Comment: What are the columns in the database?  Where does the date come from?  _Someone_ has to tell you what the numbers are. Asking here isn't going to help.

Comment: [WGS-84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) is just a reference system to map [coordinates to the globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).  Usually there are only two numbers (latitude and longitude) to define a point, sometimes a third point of altitude (like in KML) will be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the parameters for a [World file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) that allow the correct placement of raster images.

```
0.00852919145063922,  // How much longitude each X pixel represents
0.000000,             // Rotation about Y-axis
0.000000,             // Rotation about X-axis
-0.00852919145063922, // How much latitude each Y pixel represents
-117.210491069447,    // Longitude of the upper left pixel (West point)
34.8362619850852      // Latitude of the upper left pixel (North point)
```

I found my answer in this [link.](http://www.justkez.com/calculating-latlongs-for-projecting-world-fil/)